# Inconsistent media.css loading after multiple reloads

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I have an issue that seems to be inconsistent loading of my media.css file. I think this is happening because the order and the page is rendering before it hits it.

Most of the time, this correct version will load:

[image: correct]

Other times (noticed by my boss) the incorrect version will load :

[image: not correct]

I am only using 1 breakpoint to cover large mobile phones and smaller smart phones. iPads and tablets look/work fine so we don't use a mid sized break point for them.

My media queries are as follows :

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 768px) and (orientation:portrait) {//lots of styles}
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 1200px) and (orientation:landscape) {//some more stylez}
```

it is being loaded at the bottom of the head after a bunch of scripts/css for other modules etc. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to see what going on. Having said that, you should always put you CSS before any scripts in the head. Ideally, place all of your scripts (with the exception of any polyfills such as Modernizr, HTML5shiv, etc) below your content, before  the </body> tag. Try this and see if your problem still exists. If it does, please post code.

Comment: Do you want to see the order of the files in the <head> ?

Comment: A link to your code would be very helpful...

Comment: https://github.com/ckahle33/CNS_3root/blob/master/CNS_3/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. The media.css file wasn't being hit by the time the cached page contentloaded. I used this function on [require.js advanced uses page](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/faq-advanced.html) to make sure this file is loaded and then initiated the function in some responsive jQuery.

```
function loadCss(url) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = url;
     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
}

jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if (jQuery(window).width() < 768) {
       loadCss('http://cns.utexas.edu/templates/CNS_3/css/media.css');
    } 
});
```